# How to sync files from OneDrive to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, if-this-then-that, synchronization, onedrive, online-storage

The only way to sync photos on Lumia phone is via OneDrive, while I want to store them in Dropbox. The only plausible recipe on IFTTT is to sync Dropbox to OneDrive, not the other way around.

How to sync files from OneDrive to Dropbox?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no trigger available OneDrive in IFTTT, so that precludes using that. I suspect that the OneDrive API simply doesn't have a way to get that information.

Comment: I'm guessing you can get OneDrive to send you an email when a file is uploaded, but the email won't include the contents of the file. You *might* be able to fiddle with this idea and get it to work, though.

Comment: You could try a service like [Cloud HQ](https://cloudHQ.net?r=9u4p) - Note that's my referral link, don't feel you have to use it.  It does however give you access to their premium service for free for 30 days. They do also have a limited free version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you asked for IFTTT, but since it's not possible I'm suggesting other solutions:

- [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com)
- [Zapier](https://zapier.com)

Click the images to open the relevant template, it's pretty straight forward.

### Flow

[image]

### Zapier

[image]

Comment: Thanks. At that time (2014) I only knew IFTTT. I didn't know that Microsoft has a service like that too

Comment: So great :) I didn't knew if it was a matter of choice to go with IFTTT or a lack of knowledge of other services that might existed at the time

Comment: a question has to wait for 4 years to get a satisfied answer :(

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't a member of the community 4 years ago ;)

Comment: @Ooker - Did this work? Does it still work? Is it one way or both ways? Can the Reverse be done - DropBox folder(s) auto syncing to OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

You can install OneDrive and Dropbox in your computer, then having a script to automate copying files from OneDrive to Dropbox. There are programs that can do that too.

Answer (score 0):

still relevant?!

With [multcloud](https://www.multcloud.com/) you can synchronize between two accounts!

Comment: Did this work? Does it still work? Is it one way or both ways? Can the Reverse be done - DropBox folder(s) auto syncing to OneDrive? Please outline HOW?